# Office 365: Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.60 SMTP; Client does not have permissions to send as this sender

Tags: microsoft-office-365

I can send mails using an office 365 account (a@domain.com) with host as smtp.office365.com in my website. But if I set a different email (b@domain.com) for 'From' address I get the error,

> Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.60 SMTP; Client does
>   not have permissions to send as this sender

I have given 'Send as' and 'Send on behalf of' permission for a@domain.com as follows but still not working.

[image]

Both a@domain.com and b@domain.com are 'Exchange Online (Plan 1)' licensed accounts. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: At a first glance: you did nothing wrong. How long did you wait to try it?

Comment: @Lenniey thanks, it has been more than 24 hours

Comment: You say you "send from your website", can you send the mail as user b@domain.com if you use Outlook365 directly?

Comment: Why are you sending email this way? Inboxes are for users

Comment: @Lenniey yes I can send from both accounts directly from mail client

Comment: @JacobEvans this is due to two issues, 1. currently I send mails from a server using Mail Enabled, but it doesn't relay mails of same domain to outside (in this case office 365 accounts), it works fine with other domains. ex: when mails sent to anything@mydomain.com they are not sent outside, instead they are sent to local anything@mydomain.com account. 2. Mails sent from this server lands in junk as mail is hosted in office 365 and spf records. Thanks

Comment: There's a plethora of info here in correctly configuring an authenticated SMTP server for relay